# The window of relations in phpMyAdmin is blank

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make relations between tables just like [here](http://www.yourwebskills.com/dbrelationships.php), but the window that must show for choosing type of update and delete in child table, shows like pop - up and it's blank. I tried to use another browser, but it didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: Change your mysql engine to innoDB for all your tables that need a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The default storage engine MySQL uses is MyISAM, which unfortunately doesn't support relations. Check if your database objects are using that, and if yes, switch to InnoDB.

As a bonus, InnoDB will also give you transactions.

Comment: All the tables in my DB are of InnoDB type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem were the foreign keys. I haven't set them correctly.